# Azure Active Directory non-admin user access Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I need to create several users in Azure active directory and allow them to access my Azure SQL DB. What I do is create them here

[image]
And then I create them in database

```
CREATE USER [vitaliy@xxx.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [vitaliy@xxx.com];
```

But after I login, it triggers the browser-based authentication and then I get the following error

[image]

**However**, it works awesome with the AD account that set as Active Directory Admin

[image]

**I am using SSMS and 'Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA' authentication mechanizm**

Comment: Which Authentication Protocol are you using to connect?  Windows Authentication won't work.

Comment: I am using Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA

Comment: And does that trigger the browser-based authentication flow for you?

Comment: Yes it does trigger

Comment: And you set the target database in the connection dialog?

Comment: No. I just set the DB server. SSMS does not ask for the database at that stage

Comment: If you created an AAD User, you can only connect to the database.  A User is a database-level prinicpal.  A Login is required to connect to Master.  And you can set the database under the connection dialog options.

Comment: How would I specify the database in SSMS ?

Comment: Expand the "Options" of the connection dialog, and on the second tab you can specify the database name to connect directly to the database.

Comment: Worked! You are the man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: in this case, you don't have permissions to connect to the server so you should specify the database when you log in